# revealing an image in the background with jquery / css

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to achieve the following demo effects found on this page...

http://wscratchpad.websanova.com/

but instead, animate() a div block (50px by 50px) across the window from left to right, to reveal the background image.  Is this possible with jQuery and the animate() method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CSS only option. http://codepen.io/lpoulter/pen/xsywu

Is that what you where after?

or with some jquery

http://codepen.io/lpoulter/pen/HobfG

Comment: Thank you @Ipoulter, but I want the box to be smaller than the background image and to reveal part of it as it goes from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/v3ujy/

Given something like this:
CSS:

```
body
{
    background-image:url('http://www.wmeentertainment.com/weezer/imgs/weezer_logo.jpg');
}
#reveal
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
#actualbody
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:5000;
    position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="reveal">
</div>
<div id="actualbody">
    Actual page body
</div>
```

You could set the background image and set a div on top to "hide" the background image, then slide it aside with something like this:

```
$('#reveal').animate({width:'toggle'});
```

Comment: Sorry for the not so pleasing to the eye fiddle example... but I think it gets my point across.